# Word VBA: subaddress:= to the first bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, bookmarks

i am currently "writing" something that creates two bookmarks in my word document. my intention is to create one bookmark in my text and a second bookmark at the end of the document. there i will insert a picture as kind of a proof to my argument in the text. so far it worked out. i need a solution for an automation of the hyperlink. i want to create a hyperlink from the second bookmark back to the first bookmark and back again. this will allow the reader to jump from the text and to the proof and back again. i want to create several of theese bookmarks. the bookmarks have changing names that are equivalent to the selected words in the text. so i need a variable, i think.

This is my code so far, pleas be kind:

````
sub bkmrk

Dim s As String

Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy

s = Selection
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Add Name:=s + "zurückneu", Range:=Selection.Range
       .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
       .ShowHidden = False
    End With

Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
Selection.Paste


Dim b As String





Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.Copy

b = Selection
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Add Name:=b + "hinneu", Range:=Selection.Range
       .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
       .ShowHidden = False
    
End With

end sub```
````

Comment: Why are you trying to code something that requires no code? All the user need do is add the hyperlink forward/backward buttons to the QAT (if they haven't already done so) and use those.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I have no idea what a QAT is. I need to automate as much as possible because the people i work with, who are going to use this, are not even capable of hyperlinking via right mouse click... So i need a one button solution. thats it

Comment: QAT = Quick Access Toolbar. In any event, what are you going to do if you need two or more links to the same location? One location cannot hyperlink to more than one destination. The hyperlink forward/backward buttons on the QAT can handle this seamlessly.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. No, no, no. There are no links to the same spot. I want to link b to a and then a back to b. Than d to c and then c back to d. The code has just to learn which ohne ist the last. If b was the last bookmark, than b to a and a to b. If g was the last, then g to f and f to g.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it. Thanks. Here is my result.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bkmrk()
Dim s As String

Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy

s = Selection
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
.Add Name:=s + "zurückneu", Range:=Selection.Range
   .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
   .ShowHidden = False
End With

Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=s + "zurückneu", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=s 'Selection.Range

Dim b As String

Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.Copy

b = Selection
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
.Add Name:=b + "hinneu", Range:=Selection.Range
   .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
   .ShowHidden = False

End With

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=s + "zurückneu"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With

Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Words(1).Select

ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=b + "hinneu", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=b 'Selection.Range

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution remains adding the hyperlink forward/backward buttons to the QAT. This can be done by modifying each user's Word.officeUI file, which is typically located in:

```
C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office
```

Word.officeUI is a plain text file, which you can edit with VBA. There are plenty of solutions available for modifying text files. What you need to look for are the strings:

- <mso:control idQ="mso:WebGoBack"; and
- <mso:control idQ="mso:WebGoForward"

If missing, add the entries. Typical entries look like:

```
<mso:control idQ="mso:WebGoBack" visible="true" insertBeforeQ="mso:PrintPreviewAndPrint"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:WebGoForward" visible="true" insertBeforeQ="mso:PrintPreviewAndPrint"/>
```

where

- insertBeforeQ="mso:PrintPreviewAndPrint"

tells Word where to position the icons on the QAT (in this case, before the Print Preview icon).

This is a once-off exercise for each user and will be available to all documents without the need to modify a single document.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But i am only a user and not able to change such things.

Comment: Your IT Admin people should be able to roll out the QAT update for all users. Note also that, if you inserted endnotes with the pictures in them, you'd need no code, hyperlinks or QAT buttons, since endnote references automatically provide the forward/backward links...

Comment: Hi, thanks. Endnotes are a good idea. My IT-People are not going to do that. But thanks.